# How to conditionally mock error responses with msw

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, msw

The UI I'm working on is rendered differently based on the response received. I would like to test the UI when a `4xx` and `5xx` responses are received.

My api handler looks something like:

```
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { items } from './apiValues';

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('/items/', (_req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(items))),
];
```

This will always return a `2xx` response making it unable to test the UI if a `4xx` or `5xx` response is received, unless I change the handlers manually, which is tiring.

How can tests for `4xx` and `5xx` responses be tested?

Comment: What does the condition look like?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how can return different responses with the same url
like for successful responses
`rest.get('/items/', (_req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(items)))`
and maybe for unsuccessful responses
`rest.get('/items/', (_req, res, ctx) => res.networkError('Network error'))`
Then how I can choose a successful or unsuccessful responses when testing requests dependant components.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to mess with query params, you can also use the [`.use()`](https://mswjs.io/docs/api/setup-server/use) function.

1. Wherever you set up your handlers, add another array for each condition you want to test for

```
export const errorHandlers = [
  rest.get('/items/', (_req, res, ctx) => res(ctx.status(500), ctx.json(null))),
];
```

2. In your test file, import the handlers and the msw server you have set up, then inside the test, spread in the handlers in the server instance you want to use.

```
import { errorHandlers } from './handlers'
import { mswServer } from 'setupTests'

test('handles errors', () => {
  mswServer.use(...errorHandlers)
  // ...the rest of your test  
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Use search parameters to control the response for the `get` request.

Pass a variable in `req.body` to control if the response is successful or not for the `post` request.

See [Conditional response](https://mswjs.io/docs/basics/response-resolver#conditional-response)

```js
import { setupWorker, rest } from 'msw';

const worker = setupWorker(
  rest.get('/items/', (req, res, ctx) => {
    const error = req.url.searchParams.get('error')
     
    // error response
    if(error === 'network') {
      return res(
        ctx.status(400),
        ctx.json({
          errorMessage: 'Network error',
        }),
      )
    }

    // successful response
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(items));
  }),
)
```